# A Level moments of skateboard on a rail - justification for ignoring normal reaction forces

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider question 2.

$$$$

[image]

$$$$I'm fairly confident I can answer each part of the question if we assume that the normal reaction forces are all concentrated at point C.

However, what is the justification for assuming the forces are concentrated at C in the first place? Why is this assumption reasonable, in the context of A Level modelling assumptions, and in real life?

Surely, there are 3 reaction forces- 1 going up each leg (preventing each leg from penetrating the skateboard), and 1 reaction force at C (see diagram below).

[image]

Am I right in that you can consider these three forces separately, and then prove that the model is effectively the same if all the reaction force is concentrated at C?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This belongs on physics.stackexchange.

Comment: @ Joriki - even though it's a maths A Level question?

Comment: I don't know how they define math for A levels :-) Anyway, no one has agreed with me so far, so it's unlikely to be migrated there anytime soon. (That requires $5$ votes.) Still, if you continue not to get any answers, I think you'll have better chances there. If you do post there, please either delete this question or link the two so efforts aren't duplicated. (BTW, it says "Mechanics" at the bottom, [the Wikipedia article on that topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanics) starts with "Mechanics is the area of physics concerned with ...".)

Comment: "I don't know how they define math for A levels". Maths A Levels is split up into 3 sections: Pure maths (algebra, functions, calculus, etc), Mechanics (kinematics, forces etc), and Statistics.